# Disable all magento crons

Tags: cron

I don't have access to server so I want to disable all magento crons from magento backend System menu>Configuration>System>Cron.

What values should I change here so that crons will never run? Setting it to 0 will do?

[image]

THanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [configuring cron jobs for Magento on Centos Magento 1.7](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/58898/configuring-cron-jobs-for-magento-on-centos-magento-1-7)

Comment: dont have access to the server???

Comment: @MagenX how can that one be a duplicate? I don't have access to the server, only admin. Anyway, setting the values to 0 appears to have worked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting the values to 0 works. No crons are running now.