# Magento 1 - Get email if cron is not working / cronjob fails

Tags: magento-1, email, cron, exception, alert

I was wondering if there is an option in Magento ver. 1.9.2.2 to get an email if cron is not running or more important if a cronjob fails. I didn't find any configuration in backend nor any information here on StackExchange.

If I do not miss anything and there is no setting for it, how can I achieve it? Probably by writing an extension, but is there any kind of event what gets triggered when a cronjob fails? Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [configuring cron jobs for Magento on Centos Magento 1.7](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/58898/configuring-cron-jobs-for-magento-on-centos-magento-1-7)

Comment: MAILTO=me@domain.com

Comment: @MagenX How does that answer this question?

Comment: first you follow that link, then you put this comment together, and you get the idea :)

Comment: The question above is not a duplicate in my opinion and the question is a valid one. Leave open.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its not native, but its totally possible to implement. On MageStack we use a [cron wrapper](https://www.sonassi.com/help/magestack/magento-cron-configuration) to secure the cron process, provide support for `Aoe_Scheduler` and allow error capture.

Whilst I won't copy the source code here, the basic concept is pretty simple. You iterate over the different task types and capture the output from `stderr` - then send an email if it fails.

```
EMAIL_RECIPIENT="you@youremail.com"
LOG_FILE="var/log/cron.log"
CRON_ARGS=( "-mdefault 1" "-malways 1" )

RES=5
for ARGS in "${CRON_ARGS[@]}"; do
  php cron.php $ARGS >> $LOG_FILE 2>&1
  [ $RES -ne 0 ] && RES=$?
done

if [ $RES -ne 0 ] && [[ ! "$EMAIL_RECIPIENT" == "" ]]; then
  echo "Something went wrong with the cron, see attached" | mutt -s "Cron error" -a "$LOG_FILE" -- $EMAIL_RECIPIENT
fi
```

Comment: Very interesting approach/solution. Thanks for that!

Answer (score 3):

No, there is nothing built in like that, you'll need to implement your own monitoring. And don't try to do it with a Magento observer, since it won't be able to catch a non-running or crashed cronjob.

As a simple service just for cronjob monitoring I can recommend https://healthchecks.io/ - you add a ping to your cronjobs and can configure notifications when there was no ping for a certain time.

Comment: Hello, maintainer of healthchecks.io here. I haven't used these myself but I know there are Magento modules for easy ping configuration: https://github.com/janiscaunecm/Healthchecks_Magento (M1) and https://github.com/scandiwebcom/Cron-Health-Checker (M2)

Answer (score 0):

The same thing happened to a client of mine.  They wanted to be notified not just of failures but they wanted to know how long jobs were taking to run and get notified of errors.  I couldn't find something that fit what they wanted so I ended up building a small (free) notification service that checks to make sure that schedules are running on time, but also captures elapsed times and graphs them out nicely for you.  It's the [Job Heath Data Vault](https://vh.10n-software.com/), has Magento 1 and Magento 2 adapters and is free to use.